# points inverting at focal point (3d projection in python)

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I'm working on making a 3d engine but have an issue with the projection.

When I'm projecting the x,y points it gets inverted when behind the camera.

I have found this issue on other formulas, and couldn't find a solution.

Here's my code for the projection. It may be short but I figure this is the issue.

See figure for points inversion:

[image: figure 1]

```
world_coordinate=np.array([[*coordinate,1]])
        camera_coordinate = np.dot(camera.extrinsic, world_coordinate.T)
        camera_coordinate[0] *= 1
        tmp = camera_coordinate[1].copy()
        camera_coordinate[1] = camera_coordinate[2]
        camera_coordinate[2] = tmp
        image_coordinate = np.dot(camera.intrinsic, camera_coordinate)
        image_coordinate /= image_coordinate[2]
        x,y = image_coordinate.tolist()[0][0].__round__(),image_coordinate.tolist()[1][0].__round__()
```

My GitHub repository:
https://github.com/roberto-e-torres/3d-engine/releases/tag/non-production

Comment: What exactly is your programming question? Do you know the correct formula but not how to apply it in code?

Comment: how do i make the points behind the camera invisible instead of inverted